# Start and end at specified timestamps when playing video using python-vlc

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I have a list of youtube videos to be played in vlc using python. 
I am using `tafy` and `python-vlc` libraries for the same. 
I have managed to play the videos in order using the above libraries.
But now I want to play the videos between certain timestamps ( different for each video ). 
So does an API exist in `tafy` or `python-vlc` which would enable me to play the given video from a specified start timestamp to an end timestamp?

Update: Demo code

```
import pafy
import vlc

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url


Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
sleep(10)
while player.is_playing():
    sleep(1)
```

So now this plays a complete single video. I want to play it within certain ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Media` object has both `add_option` and `add_options` functions.
`pafy` falls over for me on Linux, so I can't test it but

```
Media.add_option('start-time=120.0')
Media.add_option('run-time=60.0')
```

Should start at the 2 minute mark and run for 1 minute

```
Media.add_option('start-time=120.0')
Media.add_option('stop-time=180.0')
```

Should achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use libvlc options for that. With python-vlc, the function to use to pass string to the native library is [libvlc_new](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/a63757b8087447262f9512f4ae9385e8cdc0275f/generated/3.0/vlc.py#L4644), you will have to look into this. Then use

```
Playback control:
      --start-time=<float [-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 .. 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000]> 
                                 Start time
          The stream will start at this position (in seconds).
      --stop-time=<float [-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 .. 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000]> 
                                 Stop time
          The stream will stop at this position (in seconds).
      --run-time=<float [-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 .. 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000]> 
                                 Run time
          The stream will run this duration (in seconds).
```

And more, from https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: Is there a python wrapper present for the same. For example '--fullscreen' option, when passed during instance creation, has no effect, but works when I use the .set_fullscreen() function on the instance.

Comment: I tried to use the set_position API but I keep getting this error: 
Assertion failed!


File: /home/jenkins/workspace/vlc-nightly/vlc-nightly-win64-x86_64/extras/package/win32/../../../src/player/player.c, Line 1346

Expression: speed == VLC_PLAYER_SEEK_PRECISE || speed == VLC_PLAYER_SEEK_FAST

Comment: the --fullscreen option is not what you think it is. Anyway, try using the start/stop time in libvlc_new