# Python-VLC - How to play a video at specific time?

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I have a one-hour video, that I want to only play sections of it when something triggers it.

```
from vlc import *
import os

os.add_dll_directory('D:\\VLC')
media_player = MediaPlayer()
media = Media("VID.mp4")
media_player.set_media(media)
media_player.play()

x = 0

if x==1:
   # play the video at 2:34
else:
   # play the video at 3:09
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start and end at specified timestamps when playing video using python-vlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234322/start-and-end-at-specified-timestamps-when-playing-video-using-python-vlc)

Comment: @GinoMempin - This error appears.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\VLCTestFolder\Code2.py", line 10, in <module>
    Media.add_option('start-time=120.0')
TypeError: add_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'psz_options'

Answer (score 0):

> Media.add_option('start-time=120.0') TypeError: add_option() missing 1 required positional argument: 'psz_options'

This simply means you are applying this to `Media` where in your code you have defined `media = Media("VID.mp4")`
So the `add_option` should be applied to `media`